# How to get eslint typescript to recognize interfaces in .d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint

I have a vite 3 + vuetify 3 + vue 3 project with volar extension. I have interfaces defined in some .d.ts files and I have eslint installed too but it complains about interfaces not being found. If I disable the `no undefined` rule with this

```
"overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["*.vue"],
        "rules": {
          "no-undef": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
```

then it works, and typescript and volar have no issues. So that would mean eslint is not able to recognize it.

My package dependencies look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.30.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.40.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.6.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.23",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vuetify": "npm:@vuetify/nightly@next",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.8",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.8"
  }
```

and my eslint config looks like this

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:vue/essential"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "error",
        "semi": "error"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": ["dist/**/*.js"],
    "root": true
}
```

The eslint error I get is this

```
interface EDB_Matter
'EDB_Matter' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
```

How can I make eslint recognize the interface from the .d.ts file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the `no-undef` lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.

https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors

When using TypeScript, it's recommended to disable `no-undef` rule directly as TypeScript already check for them and you don't need to worry about this.

If you really need to turn on this rule. Add those interfaces in eslint config:

```js
// .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    EDB_Matter: true,
    /* ... */
  },
}
```